# Merge DataFrames with NaN

Tags: python, merge, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have two Pandas DataFrames containing NaNs.
df2 contains some values that are not present in df1
As a result I want a dataframe which contains numbers when available in df1 or df2 otherwise keep NaN.

Example:

```
df1:
2013-12-15  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2013-12-16  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2013-12-17    0   3    6   
2013-12-18  NaN  NaN  NaN  

df2:
2013-12-15  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2013-12-16   1    2    2  
2013-12-17  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2013-12-18  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want to get

```
res:
2013-12-15  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2013-12-16   1    2    2  
2013-12-17   0    3    6   
2013-12-18  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
In [78]:

df1.combine_first(df2)
Out[78]:
            0   1   2   3
0  2013-12-15 NaN NaN NaN
1  2013-12-16   1   2   2
2  2013-12-17   0   3   6
3  2013-12-18 NaN NaN NaN

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

> Combine two DataFrame objects and default to non-null values in frame
>   calling the method. Result index columns will be the union of the
>   respective indexes and columns